# How to add two steps in before Magento 2 Checkout Form?

Tags: magento2, checkout, tabs

I have added a Tab before Magneto 2 Checkout Form and it was successful added.
But I want to add another tab So How should i Do that.

I have changed my code in **" /var/www/html/reg-dealers/app/code/Reg/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml "** that file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="mynewstep" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Module_Checkout/js/view/checkout/my-step-view</item>
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="mysteptwo" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Module_Checkout/js/view/checkout/my-step-two</item>
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="mystepthree" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Module_Checkout/js/view/checkout/my-step-three</item>
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">4</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

How to add another tab in this ?
I have added 2 other tabs but there order are not proper and on click next It goes " First on 4th Step then on 2nd then 3rd after that Final step "

I want to run like 1-2-3-4-5 Steps.
[image]

My JS file is my-step-view.js

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
],
function (
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    stepNavigator
) {
    'use strict';
    /**
    *
    * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template,
    * my_module - is the name of the your module directory.
    *
    */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Module_Checkout/checkout/mystep'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(false),


        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                'mynewstep',
                //step alias                    
                'mynewstep',
                //step title value
                'My Step Title',
                //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                    * sort order value
                    * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                    * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                    * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                */
                15
            );

            return this;
        },

        /**
                    * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
                    * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
                    * for switching to your custom step
                    */
        navigate: function () {
            var self = this;
            //getPaymentInformation().done(function () {
                self.isVisible(true);
           // });

        },


        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    });
}
);
```

My Js file my-step-two.js

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
],
function (
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    stepNavigator
) {
    'use strict';
    /**
    *
    * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template,
    * my_module - is the name of the your module directory.
    *
    */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Module_Checkout/checkout/mysteptwo'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(false),


        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                'mynewsteptwo',
                //step alias                    
                'mynewsteptwo',
                //step title value
                'My Step Two Title',
                //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                    * sort order value
                    * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                    * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                    * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                */
                15
            );

            return this;
        },

        /**
                    * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
                    * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
                    * for switching to your custom step
                    */
        navigate: function () {
            var self = this;
            //getPaymentInformation().done(function () {
                self.isVisible(true);
           // });

        },


        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    });
}
);
```

My Js FIle for my-step-three.js

```
define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
],
function (
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    stepNavigator
) {
    'use strict';
    /**
    *
    * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template,
    * my_module - is the name of the your module directory.
    *
    */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Module_Checkout/checkout/mystepthree'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(false),


        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                'mystepthree',
                //step alias                    
                'mystepthree',
                //step title value
                'My Step three Title',
                //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                    * sort order value
                    * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                    * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                    * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                */
                15
            );

            return this;
        },

        /**
                    * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
                    * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
                    * for switching to your custom step
                    */
        navigate: function () {
            var self = this;
            //getPaymentInformation().done(function () {
                self.isVisible(true);
           // });

        },


        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    });
}
);
```

How to add navigation with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second "step component" should be added one level higher in your xml.

Compare your code example with the one below. I hope you see now the issue. If not let me now so I will add more details.

```
<item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="mynewstep" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Module_Checkout/js/view/checkout/my-step-view</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
            </item>
        </item>
        <item name="mysteptwo" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Module_Checkout/js/view/checkout/my-step-two</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">3</item>
            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Comment: Updated my file and There is issue with show and and on click next it follows the wrong order.I have added 3 steps and added screenshot of it Please Check. @Janusz

Comment: You need to analyze how progress bar is generated. Look at **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/progress-bar.html** and **progress-bar.js**

Also **step-navigator.js** and **shipping.js**

Do you register steps using **step-navigator** in your new js files? Check how those files works I think you will be able to resolve your issue with this.

Comment: Thanks for your Help I Have updated my JS Files will you look into this and help me out @JanuszJanczy

Comment: I see in your js file you use "15" as sortOrder argument for every step. perhaps you should use 11, 12, 13 ;) 

Did it fixed your issue with order?

Comment: Thanks for help. I have set these 11,12,13 but it doesn't solve my issue @JanuszJanczy

Comment: What issue you have? Please be sure you work on non cached js files and use debugger if necessary to verify how your step-navigator.js process all steps with code you have added.

Comment: Thanks for your help I have solve that issue it was in my phtml file.
Will you suggest  me any post how to save input type text value or dropdown values on success checkout. @JanuszJanczy

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean. But things related to saving data to database are more related to backend developer. I'm front-end developer and in my company I discuss this with backends dev - what they need from me and what I need from them ;)

Comment: Yes you got the point I want to save the data in database.
Okk got your point Thanks for your help till then. If you found any Info. and any Link please post here it will be very helpfull. @JanuszJanczy

Comment: I have a query regarding html file which i have created.
I want to show some data using php but it just comment out that tag and doesn't show anything how could i show that data ?@JanuszJanczy

Comment: @Prits perhaps this will be helpful https://www.yireo.com/blog/1859-do-not-depend-on-window-checkoutconfig. I recommend to create new specific question about if you this resource and other (devdocs) won't be enough.

Comment: I already did will you please check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318729/how-to-show-static-cms-block-in-magento-2-html-file/318730?noredirect=1#comment456925_318730
and help me it would be really helpfull. @JanuszJanczy