# How to Show Static CMS block in Magento 2 html file?

Tags: magento2, blocks, cms

I want to Show Static CMS block in Magento 2 html file.

Comment: Let me know if still not working.

Comment: No it still doesn't work @RohanHapani

Answer (score 0):

Replace your di.xml with below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="reg_custom_checkout_block" xsi:type="object">Reg\Checkout\Model\ConfigProvider</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

Update your **getConfig()** function from this below code :

```
<?php
namespace Reg\Checkout\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface;

class ConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
/** @var LayoutInterface  */
protected $_layout;
protected $cmsBlock;

public function __construct(LayoutInterface $layout, $blockId)
{
    $this->_layout = $layout;
    $this->cmsBlock = $this->constructBlock($blockId);
}

public function constructBlock($blockId){
    $block = $this->_layout->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
             ->setBlockId($blockId)->toHtml();
    return $block;
}

public function getConfig()
{
    $config = [];
    $config['myCustomData'] = $this->constructBlock('your-block-id');

    return $config;
}
}
```

inside knockout js

```
var customData = window.checkoutConfig.myCustomData;
console.log(customData);
```

Comment: I have updated both files di.xml and Model file but doesn't get success.
Where to put knockout.js part as such not created ant file @Rohan

Comment: as you mention js file in question. you can use this inside js file.

Comment: will i add this in cms-block.js file or any other file will you please help because it show my block in my step three or anything i am not getting .@Rohan

Comment: Yes. You can add in cms-block.js

Comment: I have added that under initialize function in cms-block.js. but it shows undefined  customData in console.@Rohan

Comment: Updated my di.xml and updated my getConfig and console.log that customData but it gives me undefined.
I have Updated my both files in my Question Please Check.@RohanHapani